# Filtering GeoJSON by properties time value

Tags: javascript, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I have a GeoJSON with weather data from several weather stations. The problem is that each station is listed 3 times, because the GeoJSON contains data from 3 different readings for each station: 3 hour ago reading, 2 hour ago reading and 1 hour ago reading. The url where I get this GeoJSON from, lists data by the `-3h`, `-2h`, `-1h` sequence as shown in the picture, and as you can see, the same station is listed 3 times according to the hour of the readings.

[image: each weather station is listed 3 times]

Here is the main part of the script, where I get temperature:

```
<script>
  map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource('points', {
      'type': 'geojson',
      'data': 'https://api.ipma.pt/open-data/observation/meteorology/stations/obs-surface.geojson',
    });
    map.addLayer({
      'id': 'Temp (ºC)',
      'type': 'symbol',
      'source': 'points',
      'layout': {
        "visibility": "none",
        'text-field': ['get', 'temperatura'],
        'text-font': ['Open Sans Semibold', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
        'text-offset': [0, 0],
        'text-anchor': 'top',
        "text-size": 15
      });

    ...
</script>
```

I would like to filter (ignore) older data and just get the `-1h` weather data.

I have a very little knowledge of JS and I have tried to adapt one filter option I found here in GIS, but it didn't work for me.

```
 var yourLayer = L.geoJson(yourJson, {filter: yourFilter}).addTo(map);
 function yourFilter(feature) {
   // 1 hour ago expressed in milliseconds
  var lasthour = new Date().getTime() - (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
   // filter logic
  if (feature.properties.time > lasthour) return true;
  }
```

Is there any way to filter just the `-1h` option of my GeoJSON and display those values?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by filtering propreties time to show only -1hdata instead of -3hdata

```
<script>
  //subtract one hour from current time
  var subtracthour = new Date();
  subtracthour.setHours(subtracthour.getHours() - 1);
  // Can also subtrat extra minuts if needed
  //subtracthour.setMinutes(subtracthour.getMinutes()-15);

  // Convert to ISO Format used in this GeoJSON (2020-02-28T15:31:25)
  var dt = new Date(subtracthour).toJSON().substring(0, 19);

  // Apply the filter to get only "-1h" data 
  map.addLayer({
    'id': 'Temp (ºC)',
    'type': 'symbol',
    'source': 'points',

    'filter': [
      '>=',
      ['get', 'time'], dt
    ],

    'layout': {
      'visibility': 'none',
      'text-field': ['get', 'temperatura'],
      'text-font': ['Open Sans Semibold', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
      'text-offset': [0, 0],
      'text-anchor': 'top',
      'text-size': 15
    },

    ....

</script>
```